# Cannot show the value from ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag

I am trying to show the value of ViewBag on my .cshtml page, but the value is always empty. Below is my code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DateCalc( int? department)
{

    ViewBag.DestroyCount = 4; // docDestroyed;
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

This is what I have in my Index.cshtml :

```
<div class="card">
    <form asp-action="DateCalc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h5 class="card-header">Documents destroyed by section</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
       <div class="left">
        <label>Select Department(s)</label>
           @Html.DropDownList("department", (IEnumerable
        <SelectListItem>)ViewBag.department, new{@class="form-control"})
       </div>
       <div></div>

   <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <p class="card-text">Documents Destroyed by Section: </p>@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.DestroyCount) 
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I click on submit button, I want "Documents Destroyed by Section:" to display 4, but it does not display anything.

This is the line where I am trying to display `DestroyCount` after clicking on submit button:

```
@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.DestroyCount)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for `ViewBag.DestroyCount` was lost as you perform the redirection as:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DateCalc(int? department)
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

The data for `ViewBag` and `ViewData` is only lasted within the same request.

According to this [table](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-in-mvc1),

| ViewBag | ViewData | TempData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Its value becomes null if redirection has occurred. | Same as ViewData | TempData is used to pass data between two consecutive requests. |
| It lies only during the current request. | Same as ViewData | TempData only works during the current and subsequent request |

---

### Solution 1: Use of `TempData`

You need a `TempData` to pass the data between the requests.

> Controller

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DateCalc(int? department)
{
    TempData["DestroyCount"] = 4; // docDestroyed;
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

> View

```
@Html.Label(TempData["DestroyCount"]?.ToString())
```

> Demo

[image]

---

### Solution 2: Return View but not RedirectToAction

Another approach is return `View()` instead of `RedirectToAction()`. The data of `ViewBag` is available as it is within the same request and with no redirection.

However, make sure that you need to initialize for `ViewBag.department` before returning to Index view which I write the implementation in the `InitIndex` method, and this method is shared for both `Index` and `DateCalc` action methods.

> Controller

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    InitIndex();

    return View();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> DateCalc(int? department)
{
    ViewBag.DestroyCount = 4; // docDestroyed;
    InitIndex();

    return View(nameof(Index));
}
```

> View

```
@Html.Label(((int?)ViewBag.DestroyCount)?.ToString())
```

And notice to the browser URL, will change to "/{controller}/DateCalc".

> Demo

[image]

Comment: Side note: With `(string)ViewBag.DestroyCount`, you will get an error for (explicit) casting `int` value to `string`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I am very new to MVC. Just want to find out whether I should use  return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); or return View(Index)

Comment: Done update the answer. Thanks.